# Find an optimized linq statement to find the closest sum in a nested IEnumerable collection

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have an IEnumerable collection of 100,000 nodes and each node is a collection of int:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> List2 ;
var target = 39;
.....

for (int UserNo = 1; UserNo <= 100000; UserNo++)
{
    int minClosestTargetRequired = 0;
    int closestSum = 100000000;
    int closestSetIndex = -1;
    for (var c = 0; c < List2.Count(); c++)
    {
        int currentSum = List2.ElementAt(c).Sum(o => o);
        if (currentSum < closestSum)
        {
            closestSum = currentSum;
            closestSetIndex = c;
        }
        if (closestSum <= minClosestTargetRequired)
            break;
    }
}
```

I need to find the sum of the ints inside each level 2 node and afterward find the node with the sum less than or equal to the desired number (Target)

I tried to loop through all the nodes and find the closest sum but it's time consuming (220 mili-second for each node) and for a list of 100,000 nodes it takes so long.

Is there any faster way to find it using Linq and Lambda?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
var closestSum= list.Select (x => new {Node=x,Sum=x.Sum ()})
.Where (x => x.Sum<=target)
.OrderByDescending (x=>x.Sum)
.FirstOrDefault ()
```

Then you can access the sum via `closestSum.Sum` and the original node with the int elements by `closestSum.Node`

If you need the node's index

```
list.Select ((x,Index) => new {Index,Node=x,Sum=x.Sum ()})
.Where (x => x.Sum<=target)
.OrderByDescending (x=>x.Sum)
.FirstOrDefault ()
```

Then `closestSum.Index`

Answer (score 1):

`ElementAt` needs to iterate the entire sequence until it gets to the item that you're asking for, so calling `ElementAt` N times, where each one is searching through n items, is *very* inefficient.  Just `foreach` through the outer collection, rather than using a `for` loop with `ElementAt`.  On top of all of this, if the actual `IEnumerable` represents a query that does copmutational work, you're re-computing all of that work for every item that you pass by every time you're trying to get a new item, which means that you're re-creating and then discarding a *lot* of items.

If you *really* need to deal with indexes instead (which you should strongly consider not doing at all) then you should materialize the query into a `List` that can be efficiently indexed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, I also tried other way based on your recommendation, the speed is higher but still low for 100,000 nodes. would you please consider the new one.                                                                         var matches = from subset in MyExtensions.SubSetsOf(List1)
                    where subset.Sum() <= target
                    select subset;
    var MaxMatch = matches.OrderByDescending(i => i.Sum()).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @albertsh Now you're computing the sum of every single inner sequence twice, and you're also sorting the entire sequence of sums just to try to get the largest value.  Sorting is notably more work than computing the min or max value of a sequence.

Comment: I have also used var MaxMatch = matches.MaxBy(x => x.Sum()); instead of the second line but it takes the same time. Would you please provide your sample source code?

Comment: @albertsh That's still computing all of the sums of the inner sequence twice, although it does avoid doing the unnecessary sorting.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no replacement for your mentioned correct concerns that is also optimized in speed. Can you please provide your sample code

Comment: @albertsh You simply need to store the sum after you compute it, rather than using it for a boolean check and then discarding it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use Select(x => x.Sum()).Where(//some predicate here) ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, would you please provide a sample code based on the above requirements and sample codes .